# Vee Validate async validation fires too often

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vee-validate

I'm creating a registration form where I want to check, if an email address is already used by another user.
To achieve this I make an http call and depending on the response I show a warning.

I use vue3 and vee validate v4.

Unfortunately, the whole form is validated on every input in every field.
This means a lot of requests when filling out the form.

I would like the http request to be only made, when the email field loses focus.

I tried to use useField/useForms instead of the Form component but can't find a way to solve this problem properly.

Here is a simple example of my problem:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vee-validate@4.8.6/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

import { Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from 'vee-validate';
import * as yup from 'yup';

let call = 0;

const schema = yup.object({
  name: yup.string().required().min(8),
  email: yup
    .string()
    .required()
    .email()
    .test(
      'isEmailUnique',
      'This email is already taken',
      async function (value) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          console.log(call++);
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(value === 'test@example.com');
          }, 100);
        });
      }
    ),
});

function onSubmit(values) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>vee-validate Async Validation</h1>

    <Form @submit="onSubmit" :validation-schema="schema">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <Field id="name" name="name" type="text" />
      <ErrorMessage name="name" />

      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <Field id="email" name="email" type="email" />
      <ErrorMessage name="email" />

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </Form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Does anybody have an idea how to approach my problem?

Here is a working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vee-validate-v4-async-validation-x8wsde?file=src%2FApp.vue

Sorry, I could not get it to work as a snippet here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered caching the validation result?

Try implementing a function that memoizes the email validation so that each time it is re-evaluated, it checks if the email value has already been validated before and returns the previous result.

Here's an example:

```js
const validateEmail = () => {
  let cache = {};

  return async (value) => {
    // checks if value was previously cached
    if (value in cache) {
      // clears cache after certain amount as we don't
      // want it to continuously increase in size
      if (Object.keys(cache).length >= 10) {
        const cachedValue = cache[value];
        cache = {};
        cache[value] = cachedValue;
      }

      // return previous validation result
      return cache[value];
    }

    // validate the email value and cache the result
    cache[value] = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(value === 'test@example.com');
      }, 100);
    });

    // return the validation result
    return cache[value];
  };
};

const schema = yup.object({
  ...
  email: yup
    ...
    .test(
      'isEmailUnique',
      'This email is already taken',
      validateEmail()
    ),
});
```

While this works, I highly recommend using [useMemoize](https://vueuse.org/core/useMemoize/#usage) from [vueuse](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse) instead. It has a nicer interface and you might find other useful tools in the package.

Here's how you use it:

```
import { useMemoize } from '@vueuse/core';

const validateEmail = useMemoize(async (value) => 
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(value === 'test@example.com');
    }, 100);
  })
);

const schema = yup.object({
  ...
  email: yup
    ...
    .test(
      'isEmailUnique',
      'This email is already taken',
      validateEmail
    ),
});
```

*Note: `useMemoize` doesn't automatically clear cache. You need to manually clear it to avoid memory leaks. Check the docs.*